# Deserializing an array of values from JSON in 2048 game causes NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, json, serialization, windows-phone-8, deserialization

I'm making a 2048 clone for my university classes. I've got a custom class:

```
public class Field
{
    public int value;
    public bool stop;
}
```

And an array of those fields:

```
public Field[,] gameArray = new Field[4, 4];
```

Those are in a custom class.
Here are the methods I use to save and load this array in the item page cs file:

```
    private async void saveAsync()
    {
        string jsonContents = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(currentGame.gameArray);
        StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile textFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(saveFileName,
                                     CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        using (IRandomAccessStream textStream = await textFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (DataWriter textWriter = new DataWriter(textStream))
            {
                textWriter.WriteString(jsonContents);
                await textWriter.StoreAsync();
            }
        }
    }
    private async void loadAsync()
    {
        StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile textFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync(saveFileName);
        using (IRandomAccessStream textStream = await textFile.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            using (DataReader textReader = new DataReader(textStream))
            {
                if ((uint)textStream.Size != 0)
                {
                    uint textLength = (uint)textStream.Size;
                    await textReader.LoadAsync(textLength);
                    string jsonContents = textReader.ReadString(textLength);
                    currentGame.gameArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Field[,]>(jsonContents);
                }
                else currentGame.Reset();
            }
            update();
        }
    }
```

currentGame is an instance of the custom class. Reset(); method, well, resets all the fields, sets their value to 0. Update(); method is used to check if the player lost(not yet implemented), runs the saveAsync(); method and fills the board with lines like this(color method just changes the background color):

```
txt10.Text = currentGame.gameArray[0, 0].value.ToString();
color(b10, currentGame.gameArray[0, 0].value);
```

and the first line is what gives me a NullReferenceException. I probably messed something up with serialization and deserialization of the array, but I got literally no idea what it is and how to fix that, that's my first take on serialization and I basically copied it from the internet. Do I somehow need to pass a reference to the loadAsync(); method?

Comment: Looks like the deserialization is not happening properly. currentGame, gameArray or gamArray [0,0] is null. You need to debug the code and figure out which one of these three is null.

Comment: I have an if statement that checks if the json file is empty and if it is, it resets the board and it works perfectly well, so neither currentGame nor gameArray is null, for all I know it has to be the object I'm deserializing that's causing the bug.

Comment: currentGame is initialized from json deserialization. And if deserialization is not happening properly then it will be null. You need to check the json value. Can you share the currentGame class structure and the json which you are deserializing from ?